# MYSQL not start in Xammp

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I try to start MYSQL in the xammp it generates an error.

This is the message I got. I tried a couple of thing for solving the issue.
1. Change the port number - doesn't work
2.Change xammp/mysql/data folder values.It also doesn't work

```
3:54:30 PM  [mysql]     Status change detected: stopped
3:54:30 PM  [mysql]     Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
3:54:30 PM  [mysql]     This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:54:30 PM  [mysql]     improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:54:30 PM  [mysql]     Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:54:30 PM  [mysql]     the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:54:30 PM  [mysql]     If you need more help, copy and post this
3:54:30 PM  [mysql]     entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Have you tried running it as admin?

Comment: @Fuller Yes, I tried it. But it also didn't work